# How do I underline in Tomboy?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, formatting, tomboy

In the [Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/) note-taking application, there are options for Bold, Italic, Strikeout, Highlight, and Fixed Width, but not for Underline. Is there any way to do this at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This add-in is included in Tomboy 1.0.  It is disabled by default to avoid confusion with links, but you can enable it as djhowell has said.

Answer (score 2):

It's listed as an official [add-in](http://live.gnome.org/Tomboy/PluginList).  I could not find an option to add it on my Ubuntu install but it would be under Edit -> Preferences -> Add-Ins in Tomboy.